# What is equivalent of $("select") without jQuery for selecting all dropdown?

Tags: javascript

Maybe I did not look for well but I cannot find vanilla javascript way for selecting all dropdown in dom.

In jQuery I could use

```
var allDropdowns = $("select") ;
```

Do you know equivalent in pure javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the best "similar" experience I would suggest using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if your browser compat levels allow it.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
```

```html
<select id="a"><option>1</option></select>
<select id="b"><option>1</option></select>
<p id="whatever"></p>
```

For IE8 you should be careful, and IE7- you'd need a polyfill. For just about all other scenarios [you should be fine](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Answer (score 3):

```
var allDropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelector('select')
```

---

if it's more than one:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select')
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` * OP state "for selecting all dropdown in dom."